# Chrome removed from launcher after update

Tags: chrome-for-android, emui

I run EMUI 9.1, which completely supports Google Play Services (bought it before the ban). However, I used to update Chrome normally, but starting with version 91.xxx, it just updates fine, but the app icon is removed from the launcher, and can't start it.

Any solution? or I have to quit Chrome?

Comment: Are you using the stock launcher? Have you tried using a 3rd-party launcher? Or otherwise, uninstall and reinstall Chrome?

Comment: I tried stock launcher, and 3rd party launchers as well. Even trying to open a link won't give Chrome as an option although it is shown in installed apps list in system settings. I also tried both clearing data and disabling re-updating chrome. Nothing worked.

Comment: If it is listed in Settings->Apps & notifications, try setting it as Browser app.

Comment: Tried so. No luck.